# How can I appease Firefox when it is failing with no reported errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, reactjs, cross-browser

I have a website under development at [Pragmatometer.com](https://pragmatometer.com), and it seems to display *perfectly*, so far as I can tell, on Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Edge. Things are not equivalent with Firefox.

The page you will see if you visit the site looks different on Firefox from the others. The initial login screen on all the others is a stretched background via a jQuery plugin. Furthermore, if you create a login page on the other browsers, you will see widgets once you've logged in. On Firefox, it's essentially a white screen of death. Apart from a link at the top right that is directly present in the HTML, not built by ReactJS JavaScript, none of the four basic widgets display. Furthermore, I found nothing interesting in Firefox's debugger; there was a document.getElementById-related error, but it was not in my code and drilling down did not seem to cause anything to surface.

Are there issues with ReactJS and Firefox? I suspect something other and more, as the login screen doesn't use ReactJS and minimally uses jQuery for a background stretcher.

What should I know about developing for Firefox vs. developing with the others, now including Edge?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @JonathanHayward.. I opened it in firefox and it looks the same for me in firefox as in chrome http://imgur.com/NaTfANL

Comment: same for me what version of firefox are you using

Comment: @krilovich Thank you... and for that matter it looks more normal in a Firefox instance on my end under a Windows VM. I am running Firefox 44.0.2 under OSX 10.11.3.

Comment: I am also running 44.0.2 but on windows 10.. it could be that you have some javascript caching that might be breaking things? try clearing everything in your firefox cache.. and is it possible that you try this on another mac?

Comment: Do you have noScript or something like that installed? Looks fine here on FF

Comment: I might be able to access it from another Mac, but repeated "works for me" answers and no "I see the problem too" answers resolves this to "I have bigger things to worry about."

Comment: (N.B. @JohannesJander I don't have noScript or other add-ons beside social bookmarking add-ons; one of them may be the culprit.)

Comment: can you see your javascript file being loaded when you inspect element?? can you try some manual jquery commands through the console onto your page elements and see what happens?